# Filtering on foreign key and Many-to-many join tables

Tags: django, django-orm

I've got models where the objects are date dependent, but also the relationship between them is date dependent. So, just for illustration, I might have

```
class ValidCommonManager(models.Manager):
    ValidCommonManager(self, date):
        self.date = date

    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(ValidCommonManager, self).get_query_set().filter(
            models.Q(start__isnull=True)|
            models.Q(start__lte=self.date)
        ).filter(
            models.Q(end__isnull=True)|
            models.Q(end__gte=self.date)
        )

class CommonModel(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    valid_objects = ValidCommonManager(now())
    objects = models.Manager()

class Group(CommonModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    group_members = models.ManyToManyField(
      'Person', through='GroupMember')

class GroupMember(CommonModel):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Person)

class Person(CommonModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Now the group might exist from date A to date Z, but the membership might be different at date B and date C, which is reflected by the start and end fields in GroupMember. Now it's easy to find groups that are active at the time I'm currently processing using

```
groups = Group.valid_objects.all()
```

But I can't figure out an easy way to get the members of the group at a given date short of

```
members_of_my_group = group.group_members.filter(
            models.Q(start__isnull=True)|
            models.Q(start__lte=date)
        ).filter(
            models.Q(end__isnull=True)|
            models.Q(end__gte=date)
        ).filter(
            models.Q(group_member__start__isnull=True)|
            models.Q(group_member__start__lte=date)
        ).filter(
            models.Q(group_member__end__isnull=True)|
            models.Q(group_member__end__gte=date)
        )
```

which rapidly gets clumsy and violates the basics of DRY. I'd set `use_for_related_fields` on `ValidCommonManager`, but the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/managers/#manager-types) promise nasty things if you do that on a manager that filters.

Answer (score 1):

Related managers are just for convenience, you could always define a custom `Manager` for `Person` that would do the same thing. (Also note that as of Django 1.7 you can specify the manager you want to use for related lookups on a case-by-case basis. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#using-a-custom-reverse-manager) for more information.)

That is,

```
group_members = Group.group_members.filter(...)
```

is equivalent to:

```
class PersonManager(models.Manager):

    def get_valid_members(self, group):
        return self.filter(groupmember__group=group, 
                           Q(groupmember__start__isnull=True)...

group_members = Person.objects.get_valid_members(group)
```

Another approach would be to use subqueries:

```
group_members = Person.objects.filter(groupmember__in=
                    GroupMember.valid_objects.filter(group=group))
```

Comment: That's by-passing the ManyToManyField entirely, is it not? And it's going to return GroupMember objects, not Person objects the way group.group_members would. In that case, I've already got the manager on GroupMember thanks to the inheritance from CommonModel - I could do `group_members = GroupMember.valid_objects.filter(group=group)`, don't I?

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that gets Person records, not GroupMember records, though. Oh well.

Comment: @Paul: Sorry, I was confused by the fact that you're using `Group.group_members` to refer to `Persons` instead of `GroupMembers`. The same approach should work fine, and I've edited the answer.